# VmLck (locked memory) vs VmPin (pinned memory) in /proc/<pid>/status

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, virtual-memory

As per the man page :

```
* VmLck: Locked memory size (see mlock(3)).

* VmPin: Pinned memory size (since Linux 3.2).
  These are pages that can't be moved because something needs
  to directly access physical memory.
```

I know what is locked memory (mlock, mlockall) but I honestly didn't get the concept of pinned memory and how its different from the locked memory.

Can someone please explain with an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research I am now able to answer my own question, hope it helps future visitors.

A locked memory is never swapped out of main memory. This means that a page locked in physical memory is guaranteed to be present in RAM all the time. However, there is no guarantee that the page fault will never happen, since the kernel is still free to move the page within the physical memory.

A pinned memory is a locked memory that is pinned at a particular page frame location. This means that the pinned page can neither be swapped out of main memory nor be moved within the physical RAM and hence it is guaranteed that the page fault will never happen. This is an ideal requirement for hard realtime applications.

Read more : https://lwn.net/Articles/600502/